# How can I run the current file in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I run the current file in PyCharm?  I would like a single hotkey that will execute the current file (whether normal file, scratch file, or scratch buffer) using the project default python interpreter.  I would like to NOT have to create a custom run configuration, but just launch with the default Python configuration.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Isn't that what `Ctrl+Shift+F10` does?

Comment: YES!  That is what I was looking for!  If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I just answered myself and accepted my own answer.  If you would like to post your own answer, I would gladly accept yours.

Comment: I already did that yesterday but no worries.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I missed that.  If you would be willing to amend your answer to mention "Run in Context" so that users on other OSes or with different key bindings can make use of it, then I'll change the correct answer to yours.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As it turns out, the action I was seeking is "Run context configuration" (or "Debug context configuration" for debugging).  The default key binding on Windows is ctrl+shift+f10, or ctrl+option+R on Mac, as Ev. Kounis pointed out, although you can bind it to any key you like.

These settings can be found under the "Other" section in File->Settings->Keymap.  The easiest way to find them is to simply use the search box.

Answer (score 34):

Just right click on the tab of your file and click run "file name" or you can press CTRL+shift+F10

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I was looking for that method in the whole internet. I just forgot that we can right click on tabs in pycharm.

Answer (score 13):

The key combination you are looking for is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>. This will run the *current* script with *current being the one displayed in the viewer*.

Comment: Alt+Shift+F10 in PyCharm 2020.3.

Answer (score 8):

There are several alternatives:

1. *Run context configuration from editor* shortcut:

**Mac:** <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

**Windows/Linux:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

2. You can right click on the file, and then run **`Run 'filename'`**.

[image]

3. You can also run the shortcut to **`Find Action`** and then type run:

**Mac:** <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

**Windows/Linux:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

[image]

4. If the current file was just run, you can simply use the *Run* shortcut:

**Mac:** <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

**Windows/Linux:** <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

**References:**

[PyCharm Shorcuts for Mac OS X](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf)

[PyCharm Shorcuts for Windows and Linux](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and then select the script you want to run.

After that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> will run the last script that has been run.

Answer (score 2):

[As of PyCharm 2022.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#ux) there's a built-in "Current File" configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard shortcuts can be different on some machines. So you can just click right key on mouse and then "Run "(also you can select part of code and do the same)

Answer (score 1):

`File->Settings->Keymap->Run->Run` and see your current keymap

Comment: This will give me the option to run the current file as one of the items in the list, but won't do it immediately.

Comment: you're not specifying what keymap you have, neither your OS. You can't ask for shortcuts for an IDE without specifying any of these. So yes `Ctrl+Shift+F10` works for you, but won't work for other cases/people. That's why I pointed you to see/set your own shortcut.

Comment: That's true of course.  The way key bindings work in PyCharm is that you associate a key with an action, so if there is an existing action that I could bind the key to, that would be an acceptable answer.  The reason I didn't ask for an action specifically is that I thought that the answer may involve a macro, a plugin, etc.  As it turns out that is not the case, and I will show in my own answer, based on the shortcut that Ev. Kounis suggested.

Comment: lol sure ok mark your answer as correct. then someone who runs linux/macos or pycharm has imported other keymappings can mark your answer as not useful because ctrl+shift+f10 will not work on their machine ^^

Comment: The correct answer is to use "Run in Context", which I stated clearly in my answer.  I only mentioned "ctrl+shift+f10" in passing as an example.  Your answer is utterly and obviously wrong, so I don't know what you're complaining about.

Comment: can you point me where exactly I can find the "Run in Context" shortcut then? I'm trying ctrl+shift+f10 on my computer and nothing happens..

Comment: File->Settings->Keymap.  Then type "Run Context Configuration" in the search box.  Choose that.  (It's under "Other", and very difficult to find otherwise).  The exact language was wrong in the answer I provided, though typing "Run in Context" in the search box would take you to exactly the right entry.  I've updated the answer to provide the exact language.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you just need to run the current `.py` file in PyCharm. Right-click inside the file, and you can click the "Run file.py" button, and it also tells you the shortcut which on Mac is <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

To Run/Execute current python file in Pycharm use following keys in windows machine

> Shift+Ctrl+F10

OR

for selected code (specific line that are selected/marked)

> Shift+Alt+E

Answer (score 1):

Running file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> or via Run menu has some disadvantages. For example, you cannot use the custom redirect input file.

I have created a [project](https://gitlab.com/AndrewShark/pycharm-scripts/-/blob/main/update_current_script_path.sh) it is that will actually allow you to use currently opened py file when you press run / debug in a standard way. My project will remain actual at least until jetbrains fix non working macros in configurations. See [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-689).

Answer (score -1):

When intalling on Pycharm  select :
Add launchers dir to the PATH: Allows running this PyCharm instance from the Console without specifying the path to it.

:-)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is over 3 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here) please ask yourself: Do I really have a substantial improvement to offer? If not, consider refraining from answering.