# Python: New (2nd) file in a project does output my 1st file in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

To keep it completely simple: I opened a new project. In file lesson1.py I typed 1+2.
The output is 3
Than I opened a new file lesson2.py and I typed 3+4.
The output stays 3.
Like it is not accepting the new file. What am I doing wrong?
(I am not looking for a way to run the program like the other question which seems to be a duplicate of this, I know this is Shift-F10)

Comment: Well, clearly you're executing the wrong file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run the current file in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807305/how-can-i-run-the-current-file-in-pycharm)

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-F10 activates the new file. Thanks Aran-Fey