# Terminal in PyChram not showing me an output

Tags: python, terminal

This is my test code, but I have a more elaborate one - but they both don't work. In python 3.x.

```html
import sys


def main():
    inputfile = 'hi'
    print(inputfile)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT: This what I want to use the terminal for (and syntax errors - same problem):

```html
import csv
import sys
import json
inputfile = sys.argv[1]
outputfile = sys.argv[2]

# reading the csv
with open(inputfile, 'r') as inhandle:  # r is reading while w is writing
    reader = csv.DictReader(inhandle)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
print(data)
# writing the json
with open(outputfile, "W") as outhandle:
    json.dump(data, outhandle, indent=2)
```

Comment: Please post the errors you're getting. For the first code snippet, `hi` is not defined anywhere. I think you maybe meant to do `'hi'`, a string.

Comment: ahh sorry, I now understand. I'll make that edit. But even correcting it the thing is I'm not getting an error, whenever I call the program in PyCharm's terminal there is no output and it just prompts me again.

Comment: _How_ do you call the programm? You mentioning `Terminal`makes me think you actually use the builtin OS shell. Or do you use `Ctrl+Shift+F10` as descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807305/how-can-i-run-the-current-file-in-pycharm) for example?

Comment: Yes, I use the built-in shell. I've also just used the command line from Windows but it routes me back to PyChram's terminal to run it there(most likely because it's saved as a JetBrains PyChram file).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood by the code you've attached, hi must be wrote as `'hi'`. In your original code, `hi` is regarded as another variable being assigned to `inputfile`, but it's not defined yet.

Comment: I'm just seeing this but ignore the import sys, was using that for sys.argv, but i'm just trying to get the output of inputfile in my terminal. So far whenever call the program nothing happens

Comment: Can you upload all your codes? It's hard to tell with those.