# Add keyboard shortcut to run .py script with current file as argument

Tags: python, pycharm, run-script

Assuming I have a `.py` script in `~/Scripts/script.py`, how can I run it with the currently opened file in PyCharm 2020.3 Professional?

What I simply need is to bind a keyboard shortcut to a `python ~/Scripts/script.py <current_file>` command and see the output in console.

Edit: I guess I need a PyCharm equivalent of https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807305/how-can-i-run-the-current-file-in-pycharm

Comment: @Timorleiderman, I need almost the opposite, to run a prespecified script with the current file as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to get AutoHotKey and use that, as it has a lot of functionality, and because I don't think you can set extra shortcuts in PyCharm, both versions. You could try this though in a separate file:

```py
import os
os.system("path/to/script.py path/to/otherfile.py")
```

or if you need to give the second file as STDIN or input:

```py
import os
os.system("path/to/script.py<path/to/otherfile.py)
```

Warning though, the second will turn your otherfile.py into STDIN and therefore it will be readable line by line with `input()`
Extra
AHK Script for you:

```
#SingleInstance, force
; # is for windows key, ! is for Alt key, ^ is for control key, + is for Shift key
^+r:: ; Will use Ctrl+Shift+R
Run, python path/to/script.py path/to/otherfile.py
return
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to integrate with PyCharm, so it won't be able to automatically fill in the `path/to/otherfile.py`, right?

Comment: I think it might, if the Pycharm WINDOW name has the filename in it. I think AHK Scripting has a `str.replace()` function, so removing the extra bits would be possible. But again, I am not an AHK expert.